# Casting QObject to and from void pointer looses data?

Tags: c++, qt, void-pointers

I try to cast my object to and from a void pointer.

This is how my class inherits:

```
#ifndef EVERYTHING_H
#define EVERYTHING_H
 
#include <QString>
#include <QObject>
 
struct Base
{
public:
    const QString name;
    explicit Base(const QString& n)
        : name { n } {}
};
      
class A : public QObject, public Base
{
    Q_OBJECT
 
public:
    explicit A(QObject *parent = nullptr)
        : QObject(parent),
          Base("name") {}
};
 
#endif // EVERYTHING_H
```

And that's my main:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include "everything.h"

static A *a = new A();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    qDebug() << qint64(a);
    qDebug() << a->name;

    auto aa = static_cast<Base*>(a);
    qDebug() << qint64(aa);
    qDebug() << aa->name;

    void* v = static_cast<void*>(a);
    aa = static_cast<Base*>(v);
    qDebug() << qint64(v);
    qDebug() << qint64(aa);
    qDebug() << aa->name;

    return app.exec();
}
```

The output is:

```
1983584
"name"
1983600
"name"
1983584
1983584
""
```

1. I don't understand why the first `aa` has different address then the original pointer and works while the second `aa` points to the original address all of sudden but doesn't work.
2. How is const data lost here? In my actual app (not this minimal example) I didn't get an empty string but an assert error:

> ASSERT: "size == 0 || offset < 0 || size_t(offset) >= sizeof(QArrayData)"

Note: if A isn't QObject (just Base), everything works and I get "name" every time.

Comment: Are the QObject and template classes actually relevant to the question? In other words, if `A` just directly derived from `Base` and nothing else, would you still have the same problem?

Comment: @JarMan I assumed I wouldn't but I actually would. Just tested. Same thing without the template, I edited the question.

Comment: @JarMan just now tested that if A isn't QObject, the problem dissapears. So it's Qt-related. Still, it has to be QObject... added this to the question as well.

Comment: I think the problem is more likely due to multiple inheritance, rather than QObject particularly.

Comment: @JarMan I needed to cast from A to Base first, then from Base to void, and only then from void to Base again. Like... the same order but reversed. -_-'

Comment: Casrting to `void *`may be good for C. I strongly doubt it makes sense in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When casting a pointer up or down an inheritance hierarchy, it's not guaranteed that the underlying memory address in the pointer remains the same. Depending on the inheritance details involved, an adjustment might need to be made to ensure the resulting pointer ends up pointing to the proper part of the object. (For instance, this kind of thing can happen in multiple inheritance.)

Normally the compiler takes care of these details for you, but when you involve `void*` you stop the compiler from knowing what's going on. So it's entirely on you to do things properly.

In this case:

```
A *a = new A();
auto aa = static_cast<Base*>(a);
```

The compiler knows what adjustment to do to result in a valid `Base*`

However here:

```
A *a = new A();
void* v = static_cast<void*>(a);
aa = static_cast<Base*>(v);
```

The compiler takes the memory address in `a`, copies it directly into `v`, and then copies that directly into `aa`. No adjustments are done. So by subverting the compiler's type knowledge, you've ended up with a problem.

I'm pretty sure I've heard it said that you should only cast from `void*` back to the exact type which was casted to `void*` in the first place. This situation is an example of why. So if we change it up:

```
A *a = new A();
void* v = static_cast<void*>(a);
A* aa = static_cast<A*>(v);
Base* base = static_cast<Base*>(aa);
```

Then you should find that it works.

Comment: already figured it out but your answer explains why

Answer (score 0):

I needed to cast from A to Base first, then from Base to void, and only then from void to Base again. Order of casts need to be reversed apparently.